# Fragment Already active : Illegal State Exception

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I have gridview with items on click of item I move to Activity which has fragment. When I go to activity come back to gridview and immediately go to activity for other item it fails with following exception:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setArguments(Fragment.java:530)
       at com.buzzreel.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:81)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

This is my code of fragment in MyActivity onCreate():

```
 Fragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance();
              Bundle profileArgs = new Bundle();
              profileArgs.putSerializable("data", customObject);
              myFragment.setArguments(profileArgs);

              FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

              FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

              transaction.add(R.id.fragment_info, myFragment,
                            "MyFragment");
              transaction.commit();
```

This is getInstance method in Fragment class:

```
 public static MyFramgent getInstance() {
                      return  new MyFramgent();
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same fragment backstack name every time you click a gridview item here:

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_info, myFragment, "MyFragment");
```

what you need to do is to set that string to null:

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_info, myFragment, null);
```

or if you are using that name from the backstack then use a different name for each of the onclick of the gridviews